# Sort m.Table when checkbox is selected

Tags: jquery, sorting, sapui5

I have a problem when I try to sort dynamically my m.Table.

I have a Json as below, which provide data for my table.

```
{  
"ListeArticles": [  
    {  
        "id": "00000000000XXXXXX",  
        "text": "XXXXXXX",  
        "lot": "LOT2055",  
        "qte": "25.0",  
        "unit": "L",  
        "selected": false  
    },  
    {  
        "id": "00000000000YYYYY",  
        "text": "YYYYYY",  
        "lot": "2514AAAA",  
        "qte": "200.0",  
        "unit": "L",  
        "selected": false  
    }  
  ]  
}
```

The first column of my table is bound with "selected" as a checkbox.
Also my application contains a search field in which I enter the "lot".

What I'm trying to do is to mark the line corresponding to "lot" captured in the search field and display marked line at the beginning of the table.
I have no issue to select the corresponding line but the sorting is not working.

However, if I directly select a line in the table and I click the magnifying glass icon on the search field without “lot” information, the sorting works….

My XML View :

```
<SearchField placeholder="Recherche..." search="onSearch" width="100%" />
 <Table id="tableArticles" items="{path: '/ListeArticles'}" inset="false"> 

    <columns>
        <Column>
            <Text text="Sélection" />
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <Text text="Article" />
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <Text text="Lot" />
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <Text text="Quantité" />
        </Column>
        <Column>   
            <Text text="+ / -" />
        </Column>
    </columns>

    <items>
        <ColumnListItem> 
            <cells>
                <CheckBox selected="{selected}" widht="1em" />

                <ObjectIdentifier title="{text}" text="{id}" />

                <Text text="{lot}" />

                <Input value="{qte}" type="{Text}" description="{unit}"

                    fieldWidth="{30%}" />

                <Panel><Button text="+" /><Button text="-" /></Panel>

            </cells>

        </ColumnListItem>
    </items>
</Table>
```

Loading the model in the view controller:

```
onInit: function() {  
   var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("./model/articles.json");  
   this.getView().setModel(oModel);  
         },
```

And my function : onSearch

```
onSearch: function(oEvent){  
   var sValue = oEvent.getParameter("query");      
   var sTable = this.getView().byId("tableArticles");             
   var sModel = sTable.getModel();                              
   var sData = sModel.getProperty("/ListeArticles");

   for(i=0;i<sData.length;i++)  
   {  
       if(sData[i].lot==sValue)
       {  
         sData[i].selected = "true";                                                                                    
         sModel.refresh();             

        };  
    };  

   var oBinding = sTable.getBinding("items");  
   var oSorters = new sap.ui.model.Sorter("selected",true,false);  
   oBinding.sort(oSorters);                               
},
```

Do you have an idea of what does not work in my function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change

`sData[i].selected = "true";`

to

`sData[i].selected = true;`

It looks like the sorter is not recognizing the string value `"true"` automatically as the boolean value `true`.